# Ruby ActiveRecord field date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user Model:

```
:user_name (string)  
:birth_date (date) //date field in SQL base (Year-month-day)
```

I want to display the field Month for all users in my model.
Something like that: `User.last.birth_date.month`

How to do it?

Comment: Given that what you've written should work perfectly what is going wrong? Probably worth showing what you've tried and how the output you're getting is different from what you want.

Comment: Something like `User.pluck(:birth_date).map(&:month)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't understand if you want the username togheter with the month, or just the month. Anyway, [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) is what you want:

```
User.pluck(:birth_date).map(&:month)
#=> [4, 5, 1, 1]
```

For the username and the month:

```
User.pluck(:user_name, :birth_date).map { |u, b| [u, b.month] }
#=> [['thomas', 4], ['smith', 5], ['alfred', 1], ['jim', 1]]
```

Comment: Pluck is great, especially now it accepts multiple columns. P.s. I don't think you actually need to map after plucking. User.pluck(:user_name, :birth_date) should give the same result as User.pluck(:user_name, :birth_date).map { |u, b| [u, b.month] }.

Comment: `pluck` is the best new Rails feature since 2.3 :) `map` is necessary for retrieving the month, otherwise you would get the date

Comment: Nevermind, you are right. Forgot the whole point he only wanted the month number. :) Usually you would want to prevent further mapping, since pluck already does so.